# Shell Script: How do I add the digits of a number?

Tags: shell, int

I am making a shell script that takes a single number (length is unimportant) from the command line and adds the digits of it together. I thought I had it, but it won't work and either displays "0+3+4+5" if the command input is 345 or it displays the variables when I use expr to add them.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
i="$(expr length $1)"
s=$1

for i in $(seq 0 $((${#s} - 1))); do
    value=${s:$i:1}
    typeset -i value
    sum=$sum+$value
done
echo $sum
```

Also doesn't work when I replace it with sum='expr $sum + $value'

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `sum=$(($sum+$value))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

expr $(echo $1| sed 's/./& + /g;s/..$//')
```

For example, if the argument is `12345`, this translates it to the string `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5` and uses `expr` to evaluate it.